# GeoJSON Spec: What does it mean to extend GeoJSON without using a foreign member?

Tags: geojson

I'm confused at what these two parts of the [GeoJSON spec RFC7946](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-3.2) are referring to

You may have [Foreign Members](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-6.1)

> **Members not described in this specification ("foreign members") MAY
> be used in a GeoJSON document.**  Note that support for foreign members
> can vary across implementations, and no normative processing model
> for foreign members is defined.  Accordingly, implementations that
> rely too heavily on the use of foreign members might experience
> reduced interoperability with other implementations.

But [you MUST NOT extend GeoJSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-7)

> **Implementations MUST NOT extend the fixed set of GeoJSON types**:
> FeatureCollection, **Feature**, Point, LineString, MultiPoint, Polygon,
> MultiLineString, MultiPolygon, and GeometryCollection.

I'm confused at what is prohibited. What does it mean to extend GeoJSON without using a foreign member?

Answer (score 1):

> Implementations MUST NOT extend the fixed set of GeoJSON **types**

They're referring to the type, which is stored in `type`, for example in

```json
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "f2",
    "geometry": {...},
    "properties": {...},
    "centerline": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [-170, 10],
            [170, 11]
        ]
    }
}
```

For the key `type` you must have one of,

> FeatureCollection, Feature, Point, LineString, MultiPoint, Polygon, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon, and GeometryCollection

Whatever the type of the GeoJSON object you can extend it with "foreign members".

Comment: It means also that for example a feature must have one geometry but it cannot be extended to have two geometries. Another geometry can be placed into a foreign member.